# Splitting char on new line

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have some file input code:

```
std::ifstream temp("temp.tmp", std::ifstream::in);
char line = temp.get();
```

This is alright for now, and it works, so I am using it. My problem is that I need to check each line to see if it equals `"this"`. `std::getline();` hasn't been working to well for me. All I need is some way to split the char `line` into lines, (in a `for` loop, maybe??).

Answer (score 1):

the type of `line` is not char array, as implied in your question, but rather a single `char` variable.  I strongly urge you to look into `std::string`s instead of char array (c-style strings).  [Documentation of strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/)

Comment: but how would I split it into lines?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "lines".  As your code exists currently in the question, you can't split `line` because it's only one `char`.  It seems that you're implying that you want several strings, each of which contains a copy of a single line (`\n` separated in the source).  If that's the case, you'll need multiple `std::string` variables to hold the different "lines".  You would then use getline to fill the string variables.  Work on your question, and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline` is the way to go. If you can't get it to work, post the code in a new question.